# How to Embed google review in Django website?

Tags: django, google-places-api, google-cloud-console, google-reviews

I was going through the Google Cloud Platform Console to find out how I could embed a Google review on my Django website. I found the Google Places API to be the most relevant (not quite sure), but then I got lost with all the details, pricing, and different tiers. My case is actually quite simple. I just want to display the total number of stars a specific place has. Is there a free way to get that, which I didn't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the Google Places API, you can indeed display the average number of stars for a specific place on your website using the [rating](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#Place-rating) field. However, it's important to remember that you **must** display the Google logo and other appropriate attributions according to the [Places API Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms#:%7E:text=5.%20Places%20API,API%20Policies).

The Google Places API operates on a pay-as-you-go pricing model, meaning you will be charged based on the number of requests you  make.

Specifically, fetching details about a place including its rating, counts as a **Place Details request**, which is charged for $0.017 per call as stated on its [Usage and Billing documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#places-details).

> A Place Details call or request also generates [Data SKUs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#data-skus) (Basic,
> Contact, and/or Atmosphere), depending on the fields that are
> specified in the call or request. If NO fields are specified in the
> Place Details call or request, ALL Data SKUs are triggered, and you
> are charged for the Places Details call or request plus the cost of
> all the data.

The `rating` field falls under the [Atmosphere](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#atmosphere-data) category and is charged for $0.005 per request.

That said, retrieving the average rating of a specific place using Places API will cost you:

> $0.017 *(Place Details request)* + $0.005 *(Atmosphere Data SKU)* = $0.022 per request.

To show that the *Places API* can return averaged star ratings, using the `googlemaps` library, below is a request sent through CodeSandbox that retrieves the rating of a coffee shop using its `Place ID`.

```
from googlemaps import Client
api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"
place_id = "ChIJoZqnday3lzMR9WJ8w09DCn0"

client = Client(api_key)
fields = ["rating"]
try:
    place_details = client.place(place_id=place_id, fields=fields)
    average_rating = place_details["result"]["rating"]
    print(f"Average rating: {average_rating}")
except googlemaps.exceptions.ApiError as e:
    print(f"Google Maps API error: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Unexpected error occurred: {e}")
```

Result:

```
Average rating: 4.3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and effort spent to provide a detailed answer and description. It is very much appreciated.